# Managing date and hours of connection

Tags: php, connection

I meet some trouble while managing hours of connections.

Actualy I allow my users to be connected to the area only some hours and some days, for example Monday from 9am to 6 pm. For that  I have registered the day in the database and the hours for which they are authorised to be logged on.

The script check all this details and if it is a good time the user can be logged on, if not, it display a message with the good time and hours .

here below is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['connexion_x'])) { 
   if ((isset($_POST['pseudo']) && !empty($_POST['pseudo'])) && (isset($_POST['pass']) && !empty($_POST['pass']))) { 

 $mysql_host = "localhost";
$mysql_database = "users";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
      $base = mysql_connect ('localhost', 'root', ''); 
      mysql_select_db ('users', $base); 

       $sql='SELECT login, pass_md5, depart, fin, j1, j2, j3, j4, j5, j6, j0 FROM `gestionnaire` WHERE `login`="'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pseudo']).'"';
     $req=mysql_query($sql) or die;
     $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($req); 

      // si on obtient une réponse, alors l'utilisateur est un membre
      if ($data['login']==$_POST['pseudo'] AND md5($_POST['pass'])==$data['pass_md5']) { 
    $today_depart = strtotime(date('Y-m-d ').$data['depart']);
   $today_fin = strtotime(date('Y-m-d ').$data['fin']);
   $time = time();
   $i = date('w');
   if($data['j'.$i.'']==0)
   { $jour= "demain" ;}
   if($data['j'.$i.'']==1)
   { $jour= "aujourd'hui" ;}
        if( $time > $today_depart AND  $time < $today_fin AND $data['j'.date('w').'']='1'){

         session_start(); 
         $sql="INSERT INTO `session` SET
`temps` = now(),
`login`='".$data['login']."',
`mouvement`='1'";  
mysql_query($sql) or die;

          $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id']  ;
          $users['id'] = $_SESSION['id'] ;
          $_SESSION['login'] = $data['login'];
         header('Location: GESTION/index.php'); 
         exit(); 
      } 
      else
        {;

             $erreur = '<font color=red>Vous n\'&ecirc;tes pas autoris&eacute; &agrave; vous connecter, revenez '.$jour.' &agrave; '.date('H', strtotime($data['depart'])).' h '.date('i', strtotime($data['depart'])).'.</font>'; 
        }



    }
      // si on ne trouve aucune réponse, le visiteur s'est trompé soit dans son login, soit dans son mot de passe
      elseif ( md5($_POST['pass'])!=$data['pass_md5']) { 
         $erreur = '<font color=red>Compte non reconnu.</font>'; 
      } 
      // sinon, alors la, il y a un gros problème :)
      else { 
         $erreur = '<font color=red>Probème dans la base de données : plusieurs membres ont les mêmes identifiants de connexion.</font>'; 
      } 
   } 
   else { 
      $erreur = '<font color=red>Au moins un des champs est vide.</font>'; 
   }  
}  
}
```

The real trouble is not whith that code which works fine. the only trouble is that I actualy use the hour of the server but if I have some user overseas with different time, how can I allow them to be logged on, they can not be logged on on the same time as the users in my country.

Moreover If I use the time of their computer, they will be able to change their clock, so I really do not know how to proceed.

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: They will also be able to lie to you about the timezone they're in. You're out of luck if you want to observe their timezone, but you don't trust them to tell you the truth.

Comment: ok I understand, it won't be easy

Comment: It's not that it won't be easy, it will be impossible. The timezone is just a _setting_ in the operating system, it is not something absolute that you can _detect_ about your users; they can change their timezone just as easily as they can change their clock.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for the precision, I think I will have to find an other way, or to do an other version for the oversea's countries

Comment: You can use timezone only if you create their accounts..

Comment: Actualy I create their accounts because they are employee from my company, but the thing i that they often move to others countries for the business